# How to make all notifications in statur bar visible?

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I want to create my own Android app and my problem is that I can only see a charging icon in the status bar instead of battery, time, wifi etc.

[image: Screenshot of a mostly blank screen]

Above you can see how it looks, but there is not much to see.

In styles.xml I chose this Theme:

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

If you need more information just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my status bar was white because the colorPrimaryDark in colors.xml was white. And normally the status bar has the color of PrimaryDark.